# How to have background script and something similar to a default popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So, I understand that you cannot have background scripts and a default popup together. If this is so, how can I have something similar to a default popup (where there is some simple HTML that appears when you clicked the extension's icon) and have the background script modify the contents of that popup?

Here's the manifest.json

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Mark this position!",
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
],
```

Comment: You are wrong! You can have background scripts and default popup together in one extension.

Comment: I think what you are trying to say is only one is active at a time either popup or background page ?

Answer (score 7):

You absolutely can have both a popup (i.e. `default_popup` set) and a background page. The background page will have its own lifecycle (with `"persistent": false` it's an [Event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)) and the popup will exist as long as it's open.

I guess your confusion stems from the fact that you cannot have a popup and a `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` listener at the same time.

This is true, but there are other ways to tell your background page that the popup has opened.

You can message the background page from the popup:

```
// popup.js, should be included in the popup
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({popupOpen: true}, function(response) {
  /* process response */
});

// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(message.popupOpen) {
    /* do stuff */
    sendResponse(response);
  }
});
```

If you put the above popup code on the top level, then the background will be informed as soon as the popup opens.

While you can directly access the popup's window from the background (see [`chrome.extension.getViews`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getViews)), it's recommended that you move the UI logic into the popup itself and communicate with the background using [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) as above and shared [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).