# Disable popup and call browserAction.onClicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension with a `"default_popup":"popup.html"`.

Documentation of `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` says:

> Fired when a browser action icon is clicked. This event will not fire
>   if the browser action has a popup.

I know `browserAction.onClicked` will not fire in my extension. But can i disable popup so that `browserAction.onClicked` can fire?

**Conclusion** : While my extension is running, I want to disable `popup` and have a `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` in my `background.js`so that later some time I can call `browserAction.onClicked`. Is it possible? How? Also I would like to know If I can do the reverse meaning disable `browserAction.onClicked` and enable `popup`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable the popup (automatically enabling the dispatch of `onClicked` events) by setting the popup path to an empty string:

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: ""});
```

Likewise, you can enable the popup afterwards by providing a valid path:

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "popup.html"});
```

You can keep a listener to `onClicked` regardless - it's just that the event is not always dispatched.

Please note: you can't have the popup disabled, capture the click and then show the popup - you can only change what happens at *next* click. If you want both a popup and some event in the background, it's best to [simply message background from the popup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31378723/934239).