# Is it possible to do different action on left and right click on chrome extension icons

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to know that, is it possible to open popup on right click and redirect to some website on left click in a chrome extension.

If i am adding popup.html in manifest under page_action properties, then my background.js scripts not working, only popup opens.

My manifest.json file is below

```
{
 "name" : "Sherlock Extension",
 "description" : "Sherlock extension for drop alert datasource 
   integration",
  "version" : "1.2.3",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "page_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup" : "popup.html"
```

},

```
"background": {
 "scripts": ["lzString.min.js", "background.js"],
 "persistent": false
},

"permissions" : [
 "storage",
 "tabs",
 "https://sherlock.reports.mn/api/v1",
 "declarativeContent"
 ]}
```

Comment: Nope. Right-clicking always shows the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

There's no event you can intercept on right-click on the extension Browser/Page Action. It will open a context menu.

Notes:

- You can add your own entries to that context menu with [`chrome.contextMenus` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus).
- Having a `default_popup` overrides all `onClicked` listeners; if you want to both open a popup *and* do something in background, you'll need to [call the background from the popup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31378723/934239).